# How to pass input variable to SPARQL statement in R?

Tags: r, sparql

I am trying to get some data from dataset by using SPARQL query in R, I need to pass params to query :

```
var_1 <-'?birthday'

query <- 'PREFIX ex: <http://mypersonality.ddm.cs.umu.se/0.1/>

PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
  PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
  PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
  PREFIX op: <http://environment.data.gov.au/def/op#>

  SELECT ?userid ?birthday
  WHERE {
  ?contributor ex:userid ?userid .
  ?contributor ex:birthday ?birthday .
  }limit 30'

qd <- SPARQL::SPARQL(url=endpoint,query=query)$result
```

I have a variable var_1 and I need to pass it to query instead writ it directly (?birthday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sprintf` should help in this case.

```
var_1 <-'?birthday'



query <- sprintf('PREFIX ex: <http://mypersonality.ddm.cs.umu.se/0.1/>
                PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
                PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
                PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
                PREFIX op: <http://environment.data.gov.au/def/op#>

                SELECT ?userid %s
                WHERE {
                ?contributor ex:userid ?userid .
                ?contributor ex:birthday ?birthday .
                }limit 30',var_1)
```

You may want to try a different type instead of `%s` depending on what your input will be. Try running `?sprintf`, that should explain everything about different types.

**On another note:**

`gsub` might also be a good idea:

```
var_1 <-'?birthday'



query <- 'PREFIX ex: <http://mypersonality.ddm.cs.umu.se/0.1/>
                PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
                PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
                PREFIX fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
                PREFIX op: <http://environment.data.gov.au/def/op#>

                SELECT ?userid ?birthday
                WHERE {
                ?contributor ex:userid ?userid .
                ?contributor ex:birthday ?birthday .
                }limit 30'

query <- gsub("?birthday",var_1, query,fixed = TRUE)
```

It looks for `?birthday` references in query and replaces it with the variable `var_1`. The fixed argument is there to make sure that `ex:birthday` is not also replaced due to `?` being a wildcard in regular expressions.

Comment: it works fine, thank you, what about multiple variables?

Comment: In the case of multiple variables, you could try `mgsub` from the `textclean` package.`textclean::mgsub(query, c("?birthday", "?userid"), c("20/01/2018", "test_user"))`